# Hide all list elements that are not checked, Ruby or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How might I hide all the `<li>` elements that are not checked. What would be the best way to do this? Ruby or JavaScript?

```
<h3>Stores Offered In</h3>
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
    <% for store in Store.all %>
        <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[store_ids][]", store.id,  
@idea.stores.include?(store) %> <%= store.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <br />
```

Comment: Do you need to do it before the user's browser has rendered it, or afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Since this has been tagged with jQuery, I'd try this:

```
$('.multi-column-checkbox li input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').parent().hide();
```

Comment: That will only hide the checkbox.  need to add .parent('li')

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Is it normal to add jquery to a rails app?

Comment: @anmaree on the rails apps I've worked on, yes.  I'd say adding a front-end library like (jquery, prototype, or YUI) to any web based app that's meant to be used through a browser is a common practice

Comment: when I put this code in my app/assets/javascripts/ ideas.js.coffee file the script is not recognized. I have an ideas controller fyi. or should this script go in the application.js?

Comment: @anmaree I'd suggest asking a separate question regarding that as it's deviated from the original question.  After solving that issue, if you find that the answer to this question was helpful, please accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the basic of this tutorial first,
https://bytutorial.com/blogs/jquery/jquery-get-selected-checkboxes

When you iterate for each for loops, you can grab the parent and hide it..
by using this one. note: the $(this) represent the tickbox that is checked. and the .parent will represent the li in your case.

$(this).parent.hide();

Comment: thank you. I read the tutorial and it is hard for me to make the connection of how that tutorial helps me hide the unselected check boxes. the script: $(this).parent.hide(); where does that go?